# How do I get the block title from the plugin implementing it?

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm attempting to print the value of the title of the block in a block plugin.

```
public function build() {
    $build ='
        <div class="header-text">
            <'.$this->configuration['header-size-submit'].'>'.$this->title.'</'.$this->configuration['header-size-submit'].'>
        </div>
            ';
    return array(
        '#type' => 'text',
        '#markup' => $build,
        );
}
```

I attempted to get the value of the title by using

```
$this->title
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Why are you writing markup like that? It is a very bad practice. You should use render arrays and twig templates.

Comment: It's probably in the configuration array.

Comment: And `'#type'=> 'text'` doesn't exist. The type of markup is `markup`

Comment: I tried $this->configuration['title'] but it was empty. I needed to use '#type' => 'text' because 'markup' was escaping on my html. I was creating the markup like that so users can edit settings like the header tags used within the panel pane editor.

Comment: The best practice is to offer your users to choose from a set of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your block plugin derives from the `BlockBase` class, [`BlockBase::label()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockBase.php/function/BlockBase%3A%3Alabel/8.2.x) returns the default title for the block, but the block title is set in [`BlockBase::buildConfigurationForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockBase.php/function/BlockBase%3A%3AbuildConfigurationForm/8.2.x).

```
  $form['label'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
    '#maxlength' => 255,
    '#default_value' => $this->label(),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['label_display'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $this->t('Display title'),
    '#default_value' => ($this->configuration['label_display'] === BlockInterface::BLOCK_LABEL_VISIBLE),
    '#return_value' => BlockInterface::BLOCK_LABEL_VISIBLE,
  );
```

So, your block class should check if `$this->configuration['label_display']` is set to `BlockInterface::BLOCK_LABEL_VISIBLE`; if it is, then use `$this->configuration['label']` for the title.

That said, I feel like the code you want to implement is actually not necessary, since the `BlockBase` class already takes care of showing the block title.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to access the title by using

```
$this->configuration['label'];
```